# Matlab Plot: adjust X-axis step sizes with different length and name them deferentially?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, axis-labels

I am looking for some code for the following matlab plot, which now **I adjust the X-axis step size manually.**

[image]

As can be seen, the step sizes of Axis are different. In the above case, I have like 600 data of 3 days, where about 100 data for Monday,  300 data for Tuesday, and 200 Data for Wednesday.

As described, I have different number of data in one step. Thus, I dont want to have the same step size on X-axis, which is achieved now manually.

**Can any one help me with setting the step size or set the X-label with flexibility ?**

Comment: You can always use time instead of samples as the value for the x-axis. It does not even need to be that properly done. Just define **1** as **one day** and then the data can be placed at eg, 1/300, 1/200, or whatever is the number of samples you have.

Comment: Thanks, I did not quite get you, but I want the different steps size, say Monday I have 100 data points, Tuesday I have 300 data points, Wed I have 200 data points, how I can adjust the X-Axis according to that ? Any code samples will be well appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step size depends on what unit you use. I can give an example where you use day as a fundamental unit. The following code need to be made simpler to work with but this shows the principle in an easy way.

```
time = [1/100:1/100:1, 1+1/300:1/300:2, 2+1/200:1/200:3];
data = [3*rand(1,100), 0.5*rand(1,300)-1, rand(1,200)+7];
plot(time,data);
```